# Make: Prioritize -L (or: Ignore contents delivered by pkg-config)

Tags: makefile, pkg-config

I want to `make` a library that depends on other libraries.

I have been able to `make` the static `.a` files of the dependencies and have them along with the header files readily available in a directory. Running them through `file` confirms that I have successfully compiled these for all architectures.

When I try to make the final library, it tells me

`ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local....dylib, building for architecture-A but attempting to link with file built for architecture-B`

It is correct that the library under the mentioned path is only compiled for the host architecture A (installed via package manager). However, in the `LDFLAGS` I have `-L${libdir}/libs` (the folder where the libs are) but `make` only seems to care about the ones in my `usr/local/..`folder.

Are there other ways to specifically point `make` to check the `{libdir}/libs` folder or even make `make` ignore the paths from `pkg-config` in case it searches there first, finds the unfit files and never gets to try the ones I passed in my `LDFLAGS`?

Answer (score 1):

You write ...

> I have been able to make the static .a files of the dependencies and have them along with the header files readily available in a directory.

... but this is probably irrelevant because you seem to be trying to build a *shared* (i.e. dynamic) library.  Static libraries and shared ones don't mix very well.

> Are there other ways to specifically point `make` to check the `{libdir}/libs` folder or even make `make` ignore the paths from `pkg-config` in case it searches there first, finds the unfit files and never gets to try the ones I passed in my `LDFLAGS`?

You are focusing on `make`, but `make` doesn't have much to do with it.  It is the linker, not `make`, that performs the search and the actual link.  `make` just executes the link command you told it to execute.

But yes, you can control the linker's library search order by controlling the order of its command-line options.  Library directories specified via `-L` options are searched in the order they appear on the command line, and all of them before the linker's default library directories.<sup>*</sup>  If ensuring a proper order of arguments does not get you the link you want then it is very likely because the linker is ignoring your static libraries because it is trying to build a dynamic one.

However you should be able to bypass the search altogether by specifying a full path and filename of the library you want to link instead of using `-L` or `-l` options.  For example, instead of `-L/path/to -lfoo`, you might use `/path/to/libfoo.dylib` (or `/path/to/libfoo.a`).  You don't normally want to hardcode paths like that, but in this case it might serve a diagnostic purpose to do so.

Note also that it is rarely a good idea to link against dynamic libraries that are not installed in their intended location, especially if the libraries are not part of the same project.  It may seem at first to work ok, but it contributes to problems with finding the libraries at runtime (and dynamic libraries do need to be found at runtime, too).  The same does not apply to static libraries, but that comes with its own set of advantages and disadvantages.

---

<sup>*</sup> There's more to it than that, but this answer is already long.  Read the linker docs if you want more detail.

Comment: Thanks to your hint regarding entering the full path I realized the linker actually DID see the .a files. Turns out one of the packages produces multiple libraries - once I took that into account when building the dependency again, it didn't cause further trouble with the "final" library. All static btw, nothing dynamic if by dynamic you mean `.so`. 


Regarding your statements - what would be the recommended way of doing things here? Installing the packages only leaves me with my system's architecture - how would you make the linker point to e.g. the source files so I don't

Comment: have to compile all of the dependencies for the target architectures before compiling the library that I actually need? Is there a way to set up the make/link/build  so that it browses and compiles the source files of the dependencies and builds them before building the final library instead of expecting the compiled dependencies in the lib folder? Like, building the dependencies from source instead of accessing their compiled states?

Comment: @user2161301, the error message you presented in the question mentions a library ending in `dylib`.  This is the Mac convention for the naming of shared (a.k.a. dynamic) libraries.  If you think you're building only static libraries then something doesn't add up.  But if indeed you are building only static libraries and executables then the only issue with linking those libraries is finding them.

Comment: As for building only the architecture(s) you need, it is far out of the ordinary for a build system to build for anything other than the build host's native architecture, especially without being explicitly requested to do so.  And it is even more uncommon for a build system to compile for multiple architectures in a single build.  If you are working with projects that do that such odd things then you need advice tailored to those particular projects.